# plot decision boundary using libsvm

Tags: matlab, plot, svm, libsvm, boundary

I want to plot decision boundary for classification of iris data.Since the decision boundaries are hyper plans in 4D space, plotting the decision boundaries are not straightforward.

According to [LIBSVM FAQ page](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f804) we should do following to have w and b. Suppose the goal is to find the vector w of classes 1 vs 3.

```
coef = [m.sv_coef(1:3,2); m.sv_coef(25:42,1)];
SVs = [m.SVs(1:3,:); m.SVs(25:42,:)];
w = SVs'*coef;
b = -m.rho(2);
```

I want to plot boundary in 2D space by selecting just 2 dimensions of data. 
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is true.You should try 2 dimension that can separate 2 class appropraitely.try 1 and 3.